# way to avoid double conversion (byte[ ] to string to single) in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, string

In a low latency `HFT` application I have sockets receiving `Byte[]` messages containing stock market data.

In the vendor protocol stock prices fields are `Byte[]` containing an `ASCII` character sequence.
I.e. byte sequence [51-51-46-56] corresponds to ascii characters [3-3-.-8], equals the 33.8 number.

Actually during message parsing I convert `Byte[]` to string and then string to Single/float.

Is there a way to avoid such double conversion and convert directly `Byte[]` to single/float ?
Secondly is there a way to avoid the use of the string type which in NET is inefficient (immutable-garbage collection prone) ?

Thanks in advance.

Regards

[edit jan 2019]: this is the final solution working flawlessly from 3 years:

```
/// <summary> Read a Double precision float field in GL format from the stream and advances stream position of n (1 of field lenght flag + field lenght). </summary>
/// <returns>-1 in case of error, Double precision floating point value ROUNDED TO 8 DECIMAL PLACES in case of success </returns>
/// <param name="IniPos"> Initial Stream Position</param>
public double ReadGLFieldAsDouble(long IniPos = -1)
{
// --
if (IniPos >= 0)
    Strm.Position = IniPos;
int FLenght = Strm.ReadByte - 32; // case of "01000" SW Snapshot, field 7 doesn't exists, but in the message is a blank (32)
                                  // --early exit
if (FLenght <= 0)
    return -1; // a blank field (byte 32) returns -1
if (Strm.Length - Strm.Position < FLenght)
    return -1;
// --
double Dbl = 0;
int Cpos = -1;
int b = 0;
int sign = 1;

// --Builds as Integer with no point Separator
for (int i = 0; i < FLenght ; i++)
{
    b = Strm.ReadByte;
    switch (b)
    {
        case 45: // ASCII 45="-" sign
            {
                sign = -1;
                break;
            }

        case 46: // ASCII 46 is decimal point="." ; ASCII 44 is comma=","
            {
                Cpos = i; // decimal point position
                break;
            }

        default:
            {
                Dbl = Dbl * 10 + (b - 48); // increments as integer ASCII 48=0
                break;
            }
    }
}

// --Transforms in floating point  dividing by power of 10, multiplies by sign and returns
if (Cpos != -1)
    Dbl = (Dbl / (Math.Pow(10, (FLenght - 1 - Cpos))));
return Math.Round(sign * Dbl, 8);
}
```

Comment: First, which protocol is this? Why not use one of the available libraries eg for FIX? Second, are you sure about the sample values? The ASCII code for 3 is 51, not 53. #46 is the dot. Protocols like FIX send ASCII characters, your array may *already* be a string. You could use some transforms to get a BCD number, eg subtract 48 to get the actual digit, then use some bit shifting to get an integer, use the position of 46 as a scale indicator. Finally, *never ever* use float or double for financial transactions - they are subject to scaling errors. Use `decimal` wherever possible

Comment: Are you sure that this conversion takes up a meaningful amount of time? I imagine the socket read is 100x as expensive.

Comment: @usr in HFT even the length of the fiber matters. That said, the overall parsing performance is more imporant than parsing individual tokens

Comment: @Platypus if the byte array has a fixed, relatively small size, the fastest option would be to use a lookup array from bytes to values. 4 bytes is a single unsigned int

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thank you for your answer.
The protocol is proprietary Sungard GLTrade, not FIX. 
The byte array in fact is an ASCII string but I'm trying to optimize and reduce cpu load and Garbage collection.
I'll take in account the decimal advice, but the market prices we crunch have a maximum of 3 decimal digits, so single/float should be more than enough.
Regards.

Answer (score 6):

```
 byte[] arr = new byte[] { 51, 51, 46, 56};
 double res = 0, floatindex = 0.1;
 bool isFraction = false;
 for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
 {
    if (arr[i] == 46)
    {
        isFraction = true;
        continue;
    }

    if (!isFraction)
        res = 10*res + arr[i] - 48;
    else
    {
        res += (arr[i] - 48)*floatindex;
        floatindex /= 10.0;
    }
}
return res;
```

From a culture perspective, it assumes you always have a 'point' to mark the decimal separation (and not a coma like in French culture for instance)

Comment: i don't get the `isLessThanZero` variable name, shouldn't that be `isLessThanOne`, or more accurately, `isFraction`?

Comment: Thank You PierrOz !  
Your solution is simple and elegant.  
I'll test it for speed against the double conversion solution and I'll post results.

Comment: @MDeSchaepmeester you're perfectly right. I've edited the answer accordingly

Comment: @PierrOz Tested your solution converting 10 million ascii byte[].  

**Byte[] -> String-> Single** is  still 12-25% faster then direct conversion.
TroughPut is 3.6-4.6 Mln/sec depending on the machine.  
The CLR does a good job at **Ascii decoding** , at **single/float parsing** and garbage collecting.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible. Assuming you know the format is always like that (digits, comma and decimal digit):

float v = 0.1f* (100.0f * (buf[0] - 48) + 10 * (buf[1] - 48) + (buf[3] - 48));

or: 
float v = 0.1f * (100.0f * buf[0] + 10 * buf[1] + buf[3] - 4800 - 480 - 48);

Comment: Thank You.
But digits and decimal digits are not fixed numbers.